# Problems trying to decode an AVRO file generated an an Azure Key Vault Audit Event

Tags: python, azure, avro, azure-keyvault

I am trying to read the Audit Events generated by accesses to an Azure Key Vault. They are streamed to an Event Hub. The events appear in the Event Hub as AVRO files. An individual event appears as a file, `44.avro`, in a folder whose path specifies the time stamp of the event. For example, an event generated today (noon, 6-Nov-20) could be found at 'kv-audit-eh/security-logs/0/2020/11/06/12/00/44.avro'. So far, so good.

The problem comes when trying to read the contents of this file to verfiy the type of Key Vault access that triggered the event. An on-line utility says the file is empty. (The file is 508 bytes in size, and you can see a JSON-formatted schema embedded in it, along with some binary information.) I have used a tool to extract the JSON schema, and here it is:

```
{"namespace": "44.avro",
    "type" : "record",
    "name" : "EventData",
    "namespace" : "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging",
    "fields" : [
        {
            "name" : "SequenceNumber",
            "type" : "long"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Offset",
            "type" : "string"
        },
        {
            "name" : "EnqueuedTimeUtc",
            "type" : "string"
        },
        {
            "name" : "SystemProperties",
            "type" : {
                "type" : "map",
                "values" : [
                    "long",
                    "double",
                    "string",
                    "bytes"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name" : "Properties",
            "type" : {
                "type" : "map",
                "values" : [
                    "long",
                    "double",
                    "string",
                    "bytes",
                    "null"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name" : "Body",
            "type" : [
                "null",
                "bytes"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I saved this schema into the file `audit.avsc`. When I use the following Python code to read the file, I don't get any errors, but I don't get any output either.

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema = avro.schema.parse(open("audit.avsc", "rb").read())

reader = DataFileReader(open("44.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
for name in reader:
    print (name)
reader.close()
```

If I open the file in the Azure dashboard, it displays the message "may not render correctly as it contains an unknown extension."

So my question is: What is required to read the contents of one of these files? Any advice welcome, as I'm stumped by this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the AVRO file is empty, most of the time. The event hub was capturing all sorts of idle activity on the Key Vault. I switched off the option where the capture does not record null events. (That is, only capture an event that actually affects the Key Vault.) Once I did that, the AVRO files were a few kilobytes in size and the Python code read out audit events. The folders were no longer cluttered with empty files.

The capture setting in question was this one:

Do not emit empty files when no events occur during the Capture time window.

Check it.